# Obtaining momentum space wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, fourier-transform, normalization

Suppose a wave function $\psi (x)=C\exp(ip_0x/\hbar)\exp(-|x|/(2\Delta x)) $ is given and we are asked to find the momentum space wavefunction. Then we take the Fourier transform as follow:

\begin{align}
\phi(p) &= \frac{C}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\exp\left(\frac{ip_0x}{\hbar}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\vert x\vert}{2\Delta x}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{ipx}{\hbar}\right)\,{\rm d}x \\
&= \frac{C}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\frac{xi\left(p_0-p-\hbar/2\Delta x\right)}{\hbar}\right)\,{\rm d}x+\int_{-\infty}^0\exp\left(\cdots\right)\\
\end{align}
Now the wavefunction can be normalised to $0$, hence it is a legitimate wavefunction so we should be able to get momentum space wavefunction. But the first integral blows up as $x \rightarrow \infty$. If one argues that  $(p_0-p-\hbar/2\Delta x)$ should be negative (which is anyway not true in general) then the integral on right is bound to blow up. Then what is wrong? Or is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: You seemed to have gained a factor of $i$ on the $\Delta x$ term from nowhere. Fix this and the integral converges

Comment: FWIW, if you use `\exp` instead of `e^{}`, you don't need to `\Large` your equations to make them legible.